# Javascript book to understand coding techniques

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScipt, I could not able to understand the below code

```
 maskat.lang.Class.declare("maskat.key.KeyEventManager", {

    _static: {

        /** @scope maskat.key.KeyEventManager */

        getInstance: function() {
            var self = arguments.callee;
            if (!self.instance) {
                self.instance = new this();
            }
            return self.instance;
        }
    }
});
```

In the above code the word "_static" means what ? this is my one doubt like this I have so many doubt when I see the Javascript library codes.

I can able to write so much of code in Javascript, but I could not able understand few coding techniques like the above one.

Which book I have to refer to understand such complicated coding techniques.

Comment: _static is a property name in an object literal.  Otherwise, the coding techniques part of your question is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Answer (score 2):

`_static` is just a property of a new object being created "on the fly" and passed as an argument to the `declare` function. It's being assigned another object which has a `getInstance` property containing a function. `_static` is not a JavaScript keyword.

When you see something like `var x = { }` then you know that a new object is being created and assigned to a new variable, `x`. Inside such objects new properties are assigned using a colon, like `x = { y : 2 }`. Therefore you can access `y` like:

```
var x = { y : 2 };

console.log( x.y );
// or
console.log( x['y'] );
```

Comment: Without looking at the library, I assume it is being used by the `maskat.lang.Class.declare` to imitate a class-level attribute. (class-based inheritance in JavaScript is always an imitation, and usually achieved by a library). The problem here is not that you don't understand JavaScript, but that you don't understand the maskat library. The JS itself here is rather basic (apart from `arguments.callee`)

Comment: @Amadan, I think you posted your comment under my answer instead of the question.

Comment: Ooops: `…x is being assigned to a new object`. Strictly, a reference to a new object is being assigned to x, not the other way around.

Comment: @Am: I was just expanding upon a well-written answer. You provided strictly what JS is doing, I was trying to add to your answer by guessing at the purpose of the code (which I thought might help the OP), but I did not want to compete with a well-written answer and muddy the waters. Apparently I failed in the last objective :) . "You" refered to OP, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide the source of library for `maskat`? It's more likely to be a thrid-party library that provides a class-based like on top of JavaScript since JS uses [prototyping](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm), which is less common than class-based OOP.

There are many libraries that provide a class based OOP for javascript that simulates class-base oop. you may look on them to see pattern.

- [A Base Class for JavaScript Inheritance](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/)
- [Joose](http://joose.it/)

**Update**

Since you asked for books, I'll provide you with reference to learn JS

- [Eloquent JavaScript (Beginner)](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)
- [Cockford's Javascript Page (Advance)](http://javascript.crockford.com/)
- [Learning Advanced JavaScript (Advance))](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/)